# Updating field using AJAX in MVC3 view

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my controller method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckStock(int productId, short units)
    {

        Product model = db.Products.Single(x => x.Product_ID == productId);
        model.Units_In_Stock = units;
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(model, EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, model);
        var newModel = db.Products.Single(x => x.Product_ID == productId);

        return View("Details", newModel);
    }
```

Here is my AJAX:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".UpdateProductId").click(function () {
                var unitsInStock = 123;
                var pId = $(this).attr("data-id");
                if (pId != '' || pId != null) {
                    $.post("/Product/CheckStock", { "productId": pId, "unitsInStock": unitsInStock },
                              function (data) {
                                  $('#units-in-stock').text(unitsInStock);
                              });
                }
                else {
                    alert("Product_ID is empty");
                }
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

Here is my Link:

```
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="UpdateProductId" data-id="@Model.Product_ID">Update</a> 
    </div>
```

Here is the trimmed down table with the only affected row.

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>
        <div class="display-label">
            <table>
                <tr><td>Units_In_Stock</td><td><div id="units-in-stock">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Units_In_Stock)</div></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

I'm getting no error at all, but nothing at all is happening when I click the link except a # is being added to the querystring.  The breakpoint in CheckStock in the controller and the breakpoint in the AJAX method are not being hit.   Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key names and your CheckStockmethod parameters are not the same, you have `unitsInStock` in your ajax request but `units` in your CheckStock method, change them to match.

Comment: lol, I wasn't aware of that caveat.  Thank you!.  I'll add you as correct in 6 minutes :).